# tipsy live does not work with jQuery 1.9.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip, live, tipsy

We recently upgraded our jQuery to 1.9.0, but it broke our tipsy plugin. Its `live` functionality now causes an error.

```
$('.tooltip, abbr').tipsy({
    live: true
});

TypeError: this[binder] is not a function
```

Are there any fixes or patches for this? Googling didn't lead to anything useful.

---

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answers. I decided to try to fix the issue myself, because I couldn't find any patches.

Upon inspection the error seemed really easy to trace. The tipsy plugin can easily be patched to use the `on` functionality instead of the deprecated `live` functionality. In the tipsy plugin, I replaced the following code:

```
if (options.trigger != 'manual') {
    var binder = options.live ? 'live' : 'bind',
        eventIn = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focus',
        eventOut = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur';
    this[binder](eventIn, enter)[binder](eventOut, leave);
}
```

with:

```
if (options.trigger != 'manual') {
    var eventIn = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focus',
        eventOut = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur';
    if (options.live)
        $(document).on(eventIn, this.selector, enter).on(eventOut, this.selector, leave);
    else
        this.bind(eventIn, enter).bind(eventOut, leave);
}
```

Works like a charm. :)

Comment: search here with `jquery plugin conflict`

Comment: Great post! Where do you get `this.selector` from?

Comment: @RichPeck `this.selector` is a property of the underlying jQuery object.

Comment: Strange reactions until I replaced `$(document)` with `$('body')` and now, works like a charm. :)

Comment: thanks! exactly what i was searching for :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to include jquery migration plugin, since you are using `live:true` it make use of [jquery.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which was [removed in jquery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed).

For backward compatibility they have created a [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) which can be [downloaded here](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) and include the migration plugin to add back support for the removed methods and utilities.

I would be doing something like

```
if (options.trigger != 'manual') {
    var eventIn  = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseenter' : 'focus',
        eventOut = options.trigger == 'hover' ? 'mouseleave' : 'blur';
    if(options.live){
      $(this.context).on(eventIn, this.selector, enter).on(eventOut, this.selector, leave);
    } else {
      this.on(eventIn, enter).on(eventOut, leave);
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer to not use the jQuery migration plugin for this project. We intend not to use any deprecated features.

Comment: then will you be able to change the `tipsy` plugin, if you cannot then I think you have a problem

Comment: That's a good solution and I see many issues on github about this specific problem. I wonder why the author doesn't accept any pull requests?

Comment: This answer is better than the updated question's solution because it uses `$(this.context)` rather than `$(document)` to delegate the events.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this plugin still use `.live()` to let work the method `live` you used there, it is deprecated and has been replaced with `.on()`.

You should try to search for updated version of the plugin or try to replace it by yourself.